# How to output nodes tagged with only one term?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-9

I have many nodes with taxonomy term field "Tags"

For example:

1 node with tid: 10, 12, 20

2 node with tid: 10

3 node with tid: 10, 16, 18

4 node with tid: 10, 20

5 node with tid: 10

I try use filter Term ID = 10 in Views, but it output all nodes with term 10.

How I can output nodes tagged only one term - tid 10 (nodes: 2 and 5)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the second occurrence to verify that it exists. Here an example :

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->getQuery()
  ->condition('type', 'your_node')
  ->condition('tag.0.value', 10)
  ->notExists('tag.1.value');
```

There you are sure to have the nodes with the tag 10 and only 10.